# Can a heap for an interpreter somehow be implemented more efficiently than with a vector?

Tags: memory-management, rust, interpreter, unsafe

I am writing an interpreter in Rust for a domain specific language that should allow for a high performance implementation. The relevant properties for the heap are:

1. Programs are short (but a lot of them are executed)
2. I know, before execution starts, the maximum amount of memory needed
3. The needed memory is small
4. No de-allocation is needed until the program terminates
5. All the data is immutable once created
6. The language is statically type checked so no risk of accessing uninitialized memory
7. The language is single threaded so no shared memory

My elements in the heap have a fixed structure:

```
pub enum Data {
    Adt(u16, Vec<u64>),
    Prim(Vec<u64>),
}
```

The `Vec<u64>` contains either pointers to other elements or primitive data.
I first considered representing it directly with an enum.

This requires a lot of allocations at runtime and needs an unnecessary indirection for the `Vec`. It also wastes space for the capacity & size field (as the data is immutable and the size is statically known).

I'm relatively new to Rust and have kept my self away from unsafe code, but I think it could help here. I first tried to express what I want the functionality to be:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct Data(u64);
struct DataStore(Vec<u64>);

impl DataStore {
    fn alloc(max_size: u64) -> Self {
        DataStore(Vec::with_capacity(max_size as usize))
    }

    fn new_adt(&mut self, tag: u16) -> Data {
        let start = self.0.len() as u64;
        let header = tag as u64;
        self.0.push(header);
        Data(start)
    }

    fn new_primitive(&mut self, data: &[u64]) -> Data {
        let start = self.0.len() as u64;
        for e in data {
            self.0.push(*e)
        }
        Data(start)
    }

    fn init_adt_field(&mut self, Data(ptr): Data) {
        self.0.push(ptr);
    }

    fn get_field(&self, Data(start): Data, index: u32) -> Data {
        Data(self.0[(start + 1 + (index as u64)) as usize])
    }

    fn get_tag(&self, Data(start): Data) -> u16 {
        self.0[start as usize] as u16
    }
}
```

Can this be somehow be implemented more efficiently than with a `Vec`?. I looked at `TypedArena`, but was not sure if and how I could use it in this scenario. Will it be faster then the `Vec`? The `Vec` will never grow, as it is initialized with a capacity statically proven to be enough.

Is it possible to allocate just a memory blob and then use unsafe pointers? What are my options here?

Comment: It looks to me like this question would benefit from *discussion*, which is not StackOverflow's forte. I would encourage you to ask the question on reddit (r/rust) or the Rust Users forum (URLO).